# mysqli_query(): (42000/1064) when UPDATE SET WHERE with $_POST

Tags: php, mysqli, vbulletin

So I have 2 codes following each other up:

```
$query ="SELECT field6 FROM userfield WHERE userid='".$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']."' AND field6 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1";
if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

      $API = $row['field6'];


}
if(empty($API)) {
      echo "You don't have any information in our database!";
      $table   = $_POST["userfield"];
         $query ="  UPDATE $table SET field6='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['token'])."' WHERE userid=".$vbulletin->userinfo['userid']."";
   mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

The $link and $vbulletin code is working fine and so is the complete first part of the code.

However if field6 is indeed empty for that user(and $API returns empty) it start running the 2nd code. It uses most of the same variables however it wont work.

It gives the echo and then the error of:

> You don't have any information in our database!
>       PHP Warning: mysqli_query(): (42000/1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET field6 = '' WHERE userid=1' at line 1 in

And when I enter test in the field in goes to:

```
'SET field6 = 'test' WHERE userid=1' at line 1 in
```

I know the code is super messy and inconsistent but I have been trying to change small staff all night.

Comment: You never test if `$row` is empty.

Comment: `$_POST["userfield"]` where that's coming from, isn't being populated. Check your form and use error reporting. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and post your HTML form and keep the guesswork out of things. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`$table` has no value so your query looks like:

```
UPDATE SET field6 = 'test' WHERE userid=1
```

You never validate a valid value is provided before using it in your query so an empty value will break your query. You are also wide open to SQL injections because of this.